# Should I commit changes made to master in both master and branch, using SVN?

Tags: svn, version-control, branch

So I have a master and one branch made from it. I need to do some fix in master while I am still developing new feature in branch. Should I commit this fix to only master or only branch or both ? So after I am done with branch, I want to merge it with master, and keep changes made in both. What should I do ?

I am using SVN, but I guess it is same for both SVN and GIT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to avoid a huge discussion around branching strategies :-)

If I assume that in your current process that Master represents the live system and is therefore being used to patch a production bug. Whereas the other branch is being used for new development.

You want to fix the bug in prod, so in this scenario you should commit the change to Master, build and deploy the code to a test environment. Validate that the fix has worked and hasn't broken anything else. Then deploy to production.

Once the deployment to production is complete, merge the fix from Master to your development branch. This will ensure that you don't regress the fix when your new code goes live.

Answer (score -1):

Ok so basically these are my overall tips for versioning first you have your master branch which always should be stable and it's good practice to never commit into master or develop branches what you should do instead it's create new branches or features for small pieces of work and then merge into Master or develop branch to keep all clean and efficient my direct answer here is you should fix master then you should pull it from your branch to get the working copy of master in your current branch and then start to add new features, then when you already finished merge it with master 
Greetings, have a nice day

Comment: If I pull from master to my branch, aren't I am going to rewrite the changes in branch that I made with old master code ?

Comment: Sorry for the bad english, It's not my native language but yeah what i was basically trying to say it's for now you can work on your branch and do whatever you want, if your current branch pulled from master then the issues that needs to be fixed are in your branch also, you can fix it all in your current branch and then merge it, if there are conflicts use the ode of your branch

Comment: just tryng to say that is good practice when initializing a repository to keep master branch clean and start adding new features